# Hadoop mapreduce program fails with exitcode 127

Tags: hadoop, exit-code

Tyring to run some hadoop program. I see NameNode, Datanode, Yarn cluster URL up and running. i.e. 127.0.0.1:50070 /dfshealth.jsp, localhost:8088 /cluster/cluster, etc

But When i try to run my mapreduce program as : $ hadoop MySampleProgram hdfs://localhost/user/cyg_server/input/myfile.txt hdfs: //localhost/user/cyg_server/output/op

The program fails with logs:

> INFO mapreduce.Job (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1295)) - map 0% reduce
>   0%
>
> INFO mapreduce.Job (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1308)) - Job
>   job_1354496967950_0003 failed with state FAILED due to: Application
>   application_1354496967950_0003 failed 1 times due to AM Container for
>   appattempt_1354496967950_0003_000001 exited with exitCode: 127 due to:
>   .Failing this attempt.. Failing the application.
>
> 2012-12-03 07:29:50,544 INFO mapreduce.Job
>   (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1313)) - Counters: 0

When i did through some of the logs i notice this: nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor (DefaultContainerExecutor.java:launchContainer(193)) - Exit code from task is : 127

I am running in Windows 7, with cygwin.

Any input is greatly appreciated.

**:::ADDING MORE INFO HERE:::**
As of now i can see that the following hadoop source while execution [trying to set launch container] fails... I am adding the source URL for that file here.... (note this is not hadoop error but i am pointing out but some thing i am missing)....
Class:DefaultContainerExecutor
Method:launchContainer
Lines: from the start of the method launchContainer to 195 where it print the code.

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager/0.23.1/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/server/nodemanager/DefaultContainerExecutor.java#193

**NODE MANAGER LOG EXTRACT**

> INFO nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor
>   (DefaultContainerExecutor.java:launchContainer(175)) -
>   launchContainer: [bash,
>   /tmp/nm-local-...2936_0003/container_1354566282936_0003_01_000001/default_container_executor.sh]
>
> WARN  nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor
>   (DefaultContainerExecutor.java:launchContainer(193)) - Exit code from
>   task is : 127
>
> INFO  nodemanager.ContainerExecutor
>   (ContainerExecutor.java:logOutput(167)) -
>
> WARN  launcher.ContainerLaunch (ContainerLaunch.java:call(274)) -
>   Container exited with a non-zero exit code 127

Thanks Hari

Comment: Simply posting your older question into a new one, does not mean that this will fit better. Please have a look what causes a exit code of 127 on your platform and then come back with a SPECIFIC question.

Comment: I have reformatted it and more readable. I am not sure whats causing the exit code 127. thats actually why i am posting this question here. I would surely add more info, if i can.

Comment: The thing is, that Exit Code 127 can be caused by everything. So you need to provide either some log data, or metrics of your PC.

Comment: The exit status 127 of bash show that command is not found. Try run bash /tmp/nm-local-*2936_0003/container_1354566282936_0003_01_000001/default_container_executor.sh manually.

Comment: pensz: thanks, thats what i am trying to get at. But this program while exiting clears all tmp directory including that .sh file. So trying to see if i can do something to get that script in that .sh file persist.

Comment: still was not able to find reason for this. As the default_containe‌r_executor is getting deleted immediately. However, i switched my hadoop from pseudodistribution mode to StandAlone mode and it ran well. Note: this is not a fix. But just a work around to run my hadoop MR program. I think there is some configuration or setting i am missing or not set right thats causing this. I will leave this open and update it ...if i find something in future.. or some one will i guess!

Answer (score 3):

Hard coding the java home path inside hadoop-env.sh solved the issue for me as follows:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue when I tried to use libraries which are not included in the standard Hadoop distribution (`org.apache.lucene` in my case). Solution was to add missing libraries to yarn classpath using `"yarn.application.classpath"` configuration property:

```
    String cp = conf.get("yarn.application.classpath");
    String home=System.getenv("HOME");
    cp+=","+home+"/" + ".m2/repository/org/apache/lucene/lucene-core/4.4.0/*";
    cp+=","+home+"/" + ".m2/repository/org/apache/lucene/lucene-analyzers/4.4.0/*";
    cp+=","+home+"/" + ".m2/repository/org/apache/lucene/lucene-analyzers-common/4.4.0/*";
    conf.set("yarn.application.classpath", cp);
```