# Hadoop Streaming Job showing error /bin/java : No such file or directory

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I have installed Hadoop in my Macbook M1 2020 with MacOS Monterey 12.3.1.

I am able to successfully use hadoop and hdfs commands in my Laptop. I started using hadoop streaming following the Ubuntu tutorial in [this video](https://youtube.com/watch?v=mhisPejz-6c).

First of all I opened my local hadoop directory and found hadoop-streaming.jar.
[Location of Hadoop-streaming Jar file in Finder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9dU0.png)

Then I used 'hadoop jar' command to run Word count program in my Macbook but I am getting an error shown in the screenshot below.
[Screenshot with Hadoop-streaming error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N75gS.png)

I google this error obviously and got this [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13687099/hadoop-mapreduce-program-fails-with-exitcode-127), to which the answer is changing JAVA_HOME path in hadoop-env.sh has already been completed by me before hadoop installation.
[JAVA_HOME Path in hadoop-env.sh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUD1W.png)

Edit 1: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98Irt.png) is my .zshrc which includes correctly configured JAVA_HOME and PATH variables. Still, the error remains same.

Comment: 1) The hadoop-env file comments says not to define JAVA_HOME for Mac. 2) As the error says, `/bin/java` doesn't exist. You can verify that without Hadoop. And it means it's not accepting your configured Java home path to find the Java binary when the jobs are ran in YARN. You should also try adding `JAVA_HOME` to your `.zshrc` file

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Macbook M1 2020 with Mac OS Monterey 12.4.
I fixed it by reinstalling Hadoop using binary from Apache website (i used binary-aarch64 Release 3.3.0 [link](https://hadoop.apache.org/release/3.3.0.html)). Thanks to the answers from [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71316721/mapreduce-not-running-bin-bash-bin-java-no-such-file-or-directory).